# What is the difference between "uses" and "depends upon"?

Tags: oop, uml, terminology

In this [beginners guide to Dependency Injection](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321158/A-beginners-guide-to-Dependency-Injection) I noticed that [the UML diagram](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/IOCBeginners/di-uml.gif) distinguishes between  "uses" and "depends upon".

Since both require some form of a reference in the class that "uses" or "depends upon", I wonder: What is really the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the blockquotes about relationship types taken from [IBM Rational Software Architect documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/rreltyp.html).

"depends upon" means the following:

> A dependency relationship indicates
>   that changes to one model element (the
>   supplier or independent model element)
>   can cause changes in another model
>   element (the client or dependent model
>   element). The supplier model element
>   is independent because a change in the
>   client does not affect it. The client
>   model element depends on the supplier
>   because a change to the supplier
>   affects the client.

"uses" means the following:

> A usage relationship is a dependency
>   relationship in which one model
>   element requires the presence of
>   another model element (or set of model
>   elements) for its full implementation
>   or operation. The model element that
>   requires the presence of another model
>   element is the client, and the model
>   element whose presence is required is
>   the supplier. Although a usage
>   relationship indicates an ongoing
>   requirement, it also indicates that
>   the connection between the two model
>   elements is not always meaningful or
>   present.

As I read it "usage" is a less strict "dependency".

Comment: "As I read it "usage" is a less strict "dependency"." No - they are quite different.

Comment: @BonyT, Can you give your understanding?

Comment: If you use another object - it's internal changes are of no interest to you. But if you "Depend on" another object, then they do. That is what defines the two terms.

Comment: hmm, I wouldn't say "usage" is always internal. I declare that I use something, but I may not use it eventually, but still if used object has changed I may be affected. E.g. me and my mobile phone. But if I depend on something than I strictly require that thing to exist and, of course, if that thing changes I will be affected. E.g. me and food.

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich Thanks + 1 but those definitions only made the situation worse for me. Why isn't it possible to explain the difference so that even I can understand? :)

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich After reading this again, things are much clearer and I agree with your assessment that "uses" is less strict than "depends upon".

Answer (score 1):

> "Uses" is where one Class refers to another Class for some of it's operations.
>
> "Depends on" is where a Class A uses another Class B within it's implementation (e.g. as a parameter to a method). In this case changing Class B may necessitate a change to class A.

Note I've said Class, but it applies equally to Interfaces.

Wikipedia has a good article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28UML%29

So for example you could have a Uses relationship between a Class Driver and an Interface IVehicle which exposes a method called Drive(). Changes to the implementation of Drive do not require any changes to Driver, so you say Driver uses IVehicle.

However Class Driver has a Dependency on Class Hand, since Driver has two properties: Hand LeftHand and Hand RightHand. If the implementation of these changed, one would need to consider if Driver needed updating accordingly.

Comment: hand/driver looks more like a composition relationship, not a pure dependency?

Comment: Yeah - I know - it's not a great example - been trying to think of a better one along the same lines

Comment: I would argue all compositions are Dependency relationships, but yes - they are better described as a Composition

Comment: @BonyT Note how the definition of "Depends on" uses the word "uses". No wonder I can't understand the difference between the two. +1 For now.